# Excel: How do you create a dynamic, unique drop-down from a column with a logic statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have the following spreadsheet:
[image: spreadsheet example]

How would I dynamically add ***Column B*** to a dropdown for ***Column F***, IF ***Column A*** = Group ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an existing list to add the column B value or a new list can be created?

Comment: New list, only containing values from column B.. if they are a group.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the easiest way, but perhaps you are looking for something different? Make Column F a formula:

```
    =IF(A2="GROUP",B2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the reply.  But not exactly what I was looking for.  I want them to be able to select a group for the individuals from any of the groups in the dropdown that was created dynamically.